# How can I read a bundle's manifest before installing?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bundle, equinox

How can I read a bundle's manifest having only a JAR filename, but without installing or activating it?

I need to install bundles dynamically, but this creates a problem when I try to install a bundle with the same name and version of an installed one, even though they have different source files.

Comment: Just a general comment:  during development this kind of problem does come up occasionally.  From a deployment point of view, however, this should never happen.  bundle.version implies that bundle provides the exact same implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe create [JarFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) and read manifest element using [JarFile.getManifest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getManifest%28%29)?

Comment: I didn't know there is such an easy way to read a manifest file. Thank you, it worked!
I actually used the getManifest method and the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Though not directly answering your question, version 4.3 of the specification does allow multiple installations of bundles with the same symbolic name and version as long as the `org.osgi.framework.bsnversion` property is set to `multiple`.  I have no direct experience using it, it's just something I noticed while reading the spec.

See in particular section 4.4.1 Bundle Identifiers.

Comment: I tested it using:
FrameworkProperties.setProperty("org.osgi.framework.bsnversion", "multiple");

And it worked. However, there was a discouraged access warning. I think that's because FrameworkProperties shouldn't be used externally. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: How are you launching your (Eclipse?) OSGi runtime?  If you're using `FrameworkFactory.newFramework()`, the properties are passed in as a `Map<String,String>`.

Comment: I'm developing an Eclipse plugin. I think the framework is defined automatically in this case, right?
I use a BundleContext to manage the installation, and the only reference I make to anything related to the framework is a call to FrameworkUtil.getBundle.

Comment: Someone with more expertise with Equinox and Eclipse will have to pipe up.